# Have to scroll table view to enable didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am facing a very strange bug and have no idea what is going on. Basically the behavior is: I have to scroll my table view in order that the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` event is being sent. It does not matter how ofter I try to select a row `- didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not been sent. But after I scroll the table view (just a little bit is enough) then the next click on a cell works and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is sent.

Comment: can u show your code

Comment: It may happen when you set some view as your `First Responser`. You should add your code to your question first

Comment: As far as i know,you cant enable didselectRow method while scrolling.

Comment: I am not trying to select the Row while scrolling. Doing the scrolling _fixes_ the inability to select an row. But I have found the error meanwhile. (see answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I have found the bug. I searched thru the GIT history for the first commit where the error occurs. By comparing the version I found out that I called 'tableView.reloadData()' **on a background thread instead of the main thread**. This created this very strange behavior.